# JavaScript upload size limit

Tags: javascript

so I'm trying to set up upload size limit, but it has been unsuccessful.
 I have included the code with explanations, please hava a look and I would be very thankfull if you could help me. 
More information on wha I needм help with is after the " // "
Here's the code: `

```
     <html>
     <p id="check"></p>

     //ok so this part of <script> sends the user to "email.html" 
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function getFile(){
     document.getElementById("file").click();
     } 
     function sub(obj){
     var file = obj.value;   

     document.myForm.submit();  
     } 

          </script>
```

//here's the code for the button to upload a file (or image in my case)

```
 <form action="e-mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">  
     <div id="yourBtn" onclick="getFile()">Yes</div>  
     <div style="text-align: center; overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="file" value="upload" id="file" accept="image/*"                       
       onchange="sub(this)"                                 
       size="1"    style="margin-top: -50px;" "margin-left:-410px;" "-moz-opacity: 0;  
                  "filter: 
      alpha(opacity=0);"      "opacity: 0;" "font-size: 150px;" "height: 100px;">

     </div>
      </form> 




      <script> 
      var attachement = document.getElementById('file');
       attachement.onchange = function() {
      var file = attachement.files[0];
      if (file.size < 1000000) {       

    function sub(obj){return true; }
```

//ok so here's the problem, 
 when I include this code between 
'script' the user is not taken 
to "e-mail.html" anymore... please help!!!

```
    else { return false;} 
     } 

     }
     </script>
    </html> `
```

Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Why do you have `function sub(obj){return true; }` in the `if` statement? I think you mean: `if(file.size<1000000){ sub(obj); return true; }`

Comment: @devqon: He's overwriting the "submit the form" function from before to prevent the submission to happen. Not a very clean design.

Answer (score 0):

To go to a different page when the file is too big, you can assign the new URL to `document.location`. Note that the URL should be absolute (i.e. `http://.../email.html`).

I suggest to display an error when the file is too big and simply not submit the page. Otherwise, the user will see the new page and believe that everything was all right.

Also note that you need to do the same check on the server because an attacker might just create a POST request from scratch (without using the code from your page) to send files of arbitrary size to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Because the funtion inside of the onchange is not global. It is only available to the onchange.

would would need to change it to

```
window.sub = function (obj){return true; }
```

BUT the flaw with this is the user can change the file a second time and submit since you just removed the return false. You could either add it back in on the else OR you can do validation when the form is submitted and not onchange.